# trim does not remove letters from string

Tags: php, trim

I tried to use trim to remove the letter 'W' and 'l' from my string `$text`. But instead of the output `Hao et" i get "Hallo Welt", so trim did not worked.

```
<?php
        $text = "Hallo Welt";
        $text = trim($text, 'lW');

        echo "<p>Text = ".$text."</p>";
?>
```

**Output:** Hallo Welt

I informed myselve [here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.trim.php).

Answer (score 4):

trim works differently. it only removes letters from the side of the string.

```
$string = trim("asd Hallo asd", "asd");
```

will give you `" Hallo "`

what you need is [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
<?php
    $text = "Hallo Welt";
    $text = str_replace("l","",$text);
    $text = str_replace("W","",$text);

    echo "<p>Text = ".$text."</p>";
?>
```

also works with arrays:

```
<?php
    $text = "Hallo Welt";
    $search = array("l","W");
    $text = str_replace($search,"",$text);

    echo "<p>Text = ".$text."</p>";
?>
```

Comment: Oh thank you, i should have read the description properly next time.

Comment: @EdwardBlack: If this answer solved your problem, Please mark it as correct answer. As it will help other user to find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use `str_replace` like that :-

```
str_replace('W','',$text)
```

or try this :-

```
str_replace("W","",str_replace("l","",$text))
```

> str_replace(find,replace,string,count)

Answer (score 1):

Check better the definition of the function, it trims only from the beginning and end of a string: "Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string".

You could try using [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use array for archiving that, where you can define all of the letters that you want to remove. Something like this:

```
$vowels = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U");
$onlyconsonants = str_replace($vowels, "", "Hello World of PHP");
```

Answer (score 0):

`trim` only removes characters at the beginning and the end of your String.

If you want to remove every occurence of your letters, use `str_replace`